# SQL order by value from two columns based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table with entries belonging to some catergory. Each entry has an ID (e_ID), each category has an ID (c_ID) and there is a column to define the order of the content (sort1) holding a custom order represented by numbers.

Now a second optional category has been added. If that aplies the sorting number goes into a new (sort2) column so that the order of the primary catergory does not get overwritten.

I used to use `ORDER BY sort1` but would now need sort1 if the curent catergory is the entry's primary category and sort2 if it's the secondary catergory. All entries that belong to the same category shall be sorted by the user so, the data gets stored on two columns. Can I use both in this way in an order statement?

```
e_ID    c_ID    c2_ID   sort1   sort2
1       7       3       1       27
2       3       7       37      3
3       7       -       2       -
4       2       4       99      81

expected order 1,3,2 for categroy 7
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result in question

Comment: @VR46 I tired... One element belongs to category 3 and is on position 37 there. So its order number is on the second column.

Comment: What happens if sort1 in row 1 is 3, and sort2 in row 2 is 1?

Comment: @Dunno These are being written out by script and placed in the right column. The contraint that your case cannot occur is elsewhere.

Comment: You mean that all `sort2` are bigger than `sort1`?

Comment: @Dunno Not quite no. All I'm saying is that anything that exists in column sort1 will never exist in column sort2 for a given category. What it does is define the order of all items in a category (an item can belong to one or two categories). There will be only one 3rd item. If that three is on sort1 or sort2 depends on the question if the entry matches the category in question on the primary or secondary slot (c_ID, c2_ID). I hoped I'd get away without adding a sorting table...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(c2_id, c_id), -- put similar categories together
         coalesce(sort2, sort1) -- order according to your priority
```

If you want to limit to a particular category, then add:

```
where coalesce(c2_id, c_id) = 7
```

Comment: I altered line 1 in the data example in the question so that it has a secondary category that is not 7 instead of '-' values. What would I get back for that?

Comment: @C.O. . . . Your modification doesn't make sense.  Character strings do not sort in the same way as numbers.

Comment: There are noc characters. What I implied with '-' earlier was that there is no value, it's an int on the table so whatever default applies will be there instead of the '-' What I was trying to get at is that I'd have some rows where `c_id = 7` and `c2_id` equals whatever other catergory while I'd also have some where `c2_id = 7` while `c_id` is something unrelated. For the get all of catergory 7 case I need to sort by sort1 if `c_id=7` and by sort2 if `c_id<>7 AND c2_id=7`. That is my problem and I was wondering if your answer solves that.

Comment: @C.O. . . . "no value" is `NULL` and that is handled by `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly then the following should work:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE c_ID = 7
    ORDER BY sort1
UNION
SELECT * FROM my_table
    WHERE c2_ID = 7
    ORDER BY sort2
```

If you're not familiar with `UNION` - it simply combines two selections into one

Comment: Yes that looks right. UNION is the only way to get this done? If so I should probably restructure the whole thing and put the sorting on its own table.